# Need to build a calendar into check out page

Tags: bigcommerce

Need to build a calendar into check out page. So the customer can choose the date and time for a delivery/pick up of a product. My website runs on bigcommerce platform.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Date Field modifier option? There could be variance with different products and availability for pickup so the options could be tiered, and you could further build on that with a custom template to display depending on a customer's location.

The best start for modifying the checkout page is BigCommerce's checkout package that is found on the GitHub repo: https://github.com/bigcommerce/checkout-js